# How to make a state disappear after some time (React)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a state in useState hook and I want to make it disappear after a particular time frame. I tried using setTimeout() but it does not work.

```
export const Profile = () => {
  let { username } = useParams();

  const [bio, setBio] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(""); // I am printing this 'updated' value in my return statement
```

Return statement

```
<h3>{updated}</h3> // I want this 'updated' text to disappear after 3 sec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination with `useEffect()` and `setTimeout()` in the following manner:

```
let timeoutId = null;

export function App(props) {

  const [updated, setUpdated] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // if there's a message in updated
    if(updated.length > 0) {
      //remove previous timeout if any
      if(timeoutId !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }

      // create a timeout to remove it
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setUpdated(""), 3000);
    }
    
    // cleanup
    return () => {
      if(timeoutId !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }
    }
  }, [updated])


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={() => setUpdated("You have successfully did something!")}> setUpdated("You have successfully did something!") </button>
      <hr />
      {updated}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://playcode.io/895066